# CSS overflow Property has different behaviour in Firefox only

Tags: html, css, firefox, pseudo-element

I have a playlist as overlay for videos which should be scrollable.

```
.playlist{
    height: 150px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    border: 3px solid red;
}

.playlist li:before {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

.playlist li {
    height: 50px;
}

.playlist li span {
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    top: -50px;
    left: 10px;
}
```

A jsfiddle example of the situation here: http://jsfiddle.net/41unLxwk/4/

I use :before selector to display play- and pause buttons and the text is positioned relative. In this scenario there will be blank space in the end (only in firefox).

I know this does not happen if you do not use :before and relative positioning, but maybe there is another way to fix this.

edit: To clarify, the problem is that in firefox there is too much overflow-y in this example. I am not talking about the x-axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the offset of relative positioned elements doesn't affect the other elements, so you see the space that where `span` would be if you didn't move them.

You can fix it adding

```css
.playlist > ul {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```css
.playlist {
  height: 150px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border: 3px solid red;
}
.playlist ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.playlist li:before {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.playlist li:not(:first-child):before {
  border-top: none;
}
.playlist li {
  height: 50px;
}
.playlist li span {
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  top: -50px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="playlist">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span>Song_1</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span>Song_2</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span>Song_3</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span>Song_4</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span>Song_5</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

However, consider something simpler like

```css
.playlist > ul > li {
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin-top: -1px;
}
.playlist > ul > li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

```css
.playlist {
  height: 150px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border: 3px solid red;
}
.playlist > ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.playlist > ul > li {
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin-top: -1px;
}
.playlist > ul > li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="playlist">
  <ul>
    <li>Song_1</li>
    <li>Song_2</li>
    <li>Song_3</li>
    <li>Song_4</li>
    <li>Song_5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```